# mingw failing to create libbotan.a

Tags: mingw32, botan

I am trying to build botan from official sources using:

```
D:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32>python configure.py --cc=gcc --os=mingw --cpu=i386 --without-boost
```

all goes good, but when i use mingw32-make it ends at:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -f libbotan-1.11.a, ...) failed.
make (e=2): System nemože najsť zadany subor.
makefile:1451: recipe for target 'libbotan-1.11.a' failed
mingw32-make: *** [libbotan-1.11.a] Error 2
```

does anyone have any idea what is the reason? I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: sorry, but what is rm?

Comment: the command that make is trying to call with "rm -f libbotan-1.11.a"

Comment: i dont understand, isnt rm some parameter? so where should i have it in my path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, to compile this thanks to user26347 I figured out I need:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/coreutils/5.3.0/coreutils-5.3.0.exe/download
```

and get from there rm.exe and dlls in folder with my Makefile. this solved problem. Thanks for assistence